# Customize Index display in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to change the display/view of a dataframe index, without having to change the index (or the dataframe) itself if possible.

I have a stock inventory of products in a Pandas DataFrame, populated from a database, where column index is the numeric product id (i.e. the database primary key). E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
pid = [187402, 651348, 649001]
dt = pd.date_range("2020-01", periods=4, freq="MS")
n = [[9,90,900],[8,80,600],[7,90,300],[6,60,200]]
x = pd.DataFrame(n, index=dt, columns=pid)
x
```

```
            187402  651348  649001
2020-01-01       9      90     900
2020-02-01       8      80     600
2020-03-01       7      90     300
2020-04-01       6      60     200
```

However, when debugging, logging, etc I want to see the product names too. Given a set of names, `pname = {187402: "widget", 651348: "gizmo", 649001: "thingy"}`, I'd like to see something like this:

```
            187402  651348  649001
            widget  gizmo   thingy
2020-01-01       9      90     900
2020-02-01       8      80     600
2020-03-01       7      90     300
2020-04-01       6      60     200
```

I could easily change the dataframe, either add in a row with the names, or change the column index to strings to include the names. However this would be inconvenient and inefficient elsewhere in the code (e.g. need to keep the column index values matching the database key).

I really just want to change the *view* of the dataframe index, not change the dataframe/index itself.

I suspect I could use [pandas.Index.format](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.format.html#pandas-index-format) if I was working in Jupyter or similar, but we're generally developing and debugging with the console within Pycharm or VScode (or even Spyder) so I need it to display there.

I'm not adverse to subclassing pandas.Index if that would work? But if so what method would I need to override?

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to create a sublevel for each column:

```
x.columns = tuple(zip(x.columns, x.columns.map(pname)))
print(x)

# Output
           187402 651348 649001
           widget  gizmo thingy
2020-01-01      9     90    900
2020-02-01      8     80    600
2020-03-01      7     90    300
2020-04-01      6     60    200
```

The drawback is now when you select a single column, you get a `DataFrame` instead of a `Series`:

```
# After
>>> x[651348]  # you can use .squeeze() to get a Series
            gizmo
2020-01-01     90
2020-02-01     80
2020-03-01     90
2020-04-01     60

# Before
>>> x
2020-01-01    90
2020-02-01    80
2020-03-01    90
2020-04-01    60
Freq: MS, Name: 651348, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks @Corralien, a nice idea. Certainly the display looks spot on. In addition to the extra index level, more generally there might be problems since the product names can change (but the IDs don't), so we might get mismatched indexes...